# Multiple Sample Equality-of-Distributions Test For Panel Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, panel-data, kruskal-wallis-test, anderson-darling-test

Suppose I have *repeated* time observations for 800 meter sprint for a group of athletes over the course of a season. **I would like to test the hypothesis that all the times are drawn from the same unspecified distribution (i.e., that the distributions of each athlete's finishing times are all the same).** The number of trials for each athlete may be somewhat different. I am willing to assume that athletes do not influence one another through some sort of competitive effect (Bob doesn't run faster because Bill is ahead), but that each athlete's performances are correlated over time.

Are there any simple hypothesis tests that can handle this? My first inclination was a k-sample Anderson Darling test or the Kruskal-Wallis equality-of-populations rank test, but I am not sure if these can be used on panel data since each athlete's performance over time is not independent. I have only seen these tests applied to groups within a cross-section, like testing for the equality of the median income distribution across all [four census regions](http://www.i-italy.org/files/55image/where%20we%20live/US%20Census%20Regions%20and%20Divisions.png) simultaneously with US state-level data. Instead, could I use these to test whether the distribution for each state's median income over time looks like all the other states' distributions?

Comment: Do you wish to test the hypothesis that the distributions of finishing times in each race are the same or that the distributions of each *athlete's* finishing times are the same? The wording of the question is ambiguous. What is the nature of lack of independence in the data?

Comment: @whuber Please let me know if something remains unclear.